# Injecting a parameter with value into a route in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-headers, laravel-blade

Assume a page with multiple HTTP request parameters `filter=on&page=4` and so on. Those parameters are injected in the search form.

I need to have a button outside of the form that keeps the parameters, but adds another one `download=csv` into it. And that has to be done in the Blade template file, not in the `php` file (no $request variable available).

Something along the lines of this:

```php
<a href="{{ \Request::merge(["download" => "csv"])->fullUrl() }}" class="btn btn=primary">Download</a>
```

But the code above doesn't seem to work. It doesn't return the URL with the parameter in it. It just returns the URL that was prior to that, aka the injection doesn't happen.

Comment: tried with request()->input() ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<a href="{{ request()->fullUrlWithQuery(['download' => 'csv']) }}" class="btn btn=primary">Download</a>
```

Comment: That does not work. It just creates the same URL with the 'download' parameter. It does not keep the rest of the parameters

Comment: What version of laravel? How are you "injecting" your parameters? The above code should be working fine. You mention that "Those parameters are injected in the search form" so i don't know if that means you're doing that via javascript, which might be why it's not working.